# How to navigate from one screen to another screen

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How to navigate from one Activity screen to another Activity screen? In the first screen I'm having one button if I click the button it has to move to another Activity screen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(action));
    }
};

Button button = (Button) findViewById(id);
button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

Comment: That is the id of the component.

Answer (score 22):

The most trivial case (called from activity):

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityToLaunch.class));
```

More details here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Answer (score 16):

```
Button x.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(y.this, Activity.class);
        startActivity(i);                   
    }
});
```

Here we've defined a listener for Button x.  The OS will call this method and start the Activity referenced in Intent i.

Here's the official tutorial example:
http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex2.html

Comment: wait, does this even compile?

Answer (score 11):

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {      

        startActivity(new Intent(TestActivity.this,second.class));

    }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    Intent myintent = new Intent(currentclass.this, nextactivity.class);
    startActivity(myintent);                               
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This task can be accomplished using one of the android's main building block named as Intents and One of the methods `public void startActivity (Intent intent)` which belongs to your Activity class.

An intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed. It can be used with startActivity to launch an Activity, broadcastIntent to send it to any interested BroadcastReceiver components, and startService(Intent) or bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int) to communicate with a background Service.

An Intent provides a facility for performing late runtime binding between the code in different applications. Its most significant use is in the launching of activities, where it can be thought of as the glue between activities. It is basically a passive data structure holding an abstract description of an action to be performed.

Refer the official docs -- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

`public void startActivity (Intent intent)` -- Used to launch a new activity.

So suppose you have two Activity class and on a button click's `OnClickListener()` you wanna move from one Activity to another then  --

1. **PresentActivity** -- This is your current activity from which you want to go the second activity.
2. **NextActivity** -- This is your next Activity on which you want to move.

So the Intent would be like this

```
Intent(PresentActivity.this, NextActivity.class)
```

Finally this will be the complete code

```
  public class PresentActivity extends Activity {
        protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);

            setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

            final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Perform action on click   

                    Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(PresentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);

                    // currentContext.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);

                    PresentActivity.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This exmple is related to button click you can use the code anywhere which is written inside button click's `OnClickListener()` at any place where you want to switch between your activities.

Answer (score 4):

```
final Context cont = this;
Button btnClickABC =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClickABC);
btnClickABC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                   
                startActivity(new Intent(cont, NextActivity.class));

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use following code..I hope this will help you.

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.xxx);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

**xxx** is id from your xml of your Button.

Answer (score 1):

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,newActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

Switching from one activity to another is really simple, but tricky for a new one.
Your next class must be defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`. This is tester class:

```
<activity
  android:name=".Tester"
  android:label="@string/title_activity_tester" >`enter code here`
</activity>


final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);// btnGo is id 
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, Tester.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to the next screen using these code snippets:

*Kotlin*

```
startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java))
```

*Java*

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class))
```

Here's a reference: [Android Developers - Starting another activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity)

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intentobj=new Intent(FromActivity.this,ToActivity.class);
startActivity(intentobj);
```

> or you can simply use

```
startActivity(new Intent(FromActivity.this,ToActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin (if you are in an activity)

```
    buttonToClick.setOnClickListener{     startActivity(this,YourDestinationActivity::class.java)
        }
```

If you are in a fragment

```
        buttonToClick.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(requireActivity, YourDestinationActivity::class.java)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method `fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)` add this.

```
your_btn_id.setOnClickListener{

            val intent = Intent(this, yourpagename::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Until now if it doesn't work then, check if these two files are added or not,

```
import android.content.Intent
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_otp.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 Button my_btn;
 my_btn = findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
 my_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button navigate;
navigate = findViewById(R.id.button);
navigate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Navigate another Activity",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your answer to explain what this code does and how it improves on the many existing answers this 11-year-old question has, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to XML file and add Onclick = "opennewactivity" in button xml.

Then go to java code and create class opennewactivity you can just make it my clciking alt+Enter in xml code's "opennewactivity". in that just write

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, newacivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and if you want user to not get back to first activity again then just write this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, newactivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Cartoon_card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        
        {
            newActivity();
            
        }
    });
    
}
public void newActivity()
{
    Intent selectClass= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.example.fyp.videoplayer.class);
    startActivity(selectClass);
    
}
```