# How to navigate to another screen

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to navigate from one screen to another screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102050/how-to-navigate-from-one-screen-to-another-screen)

I am new to android development. can you pleas tell me, how to navigate from one Activity screen to another Activity screen .In the first screen i m having one ListView  of 4 components, if i click on one of them it has to move to another Activity screen. 
What methods the new screen should implement so as to go to some next screen.
I am adding my code for reference. GetParameter.class is the new activity to be called. This is not working. what might be the reason?

```
       public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
   {
    if (position == 0) {

        startActivity(new Intent(this, GetParameter.class));

        GlobalFunctions.startCommonDate(1, 2, 1);
        startActivity(new Intent(this, newone.class));

    } else if (position == 1) {
        GlobalFunctions.startCommonDate(2, 2, 1);
        startActivity(new Intent(this, newone.class));

    } else if (position == 2) {
        GlobalFunctions.startCommonDate(3, 2, 1);
        startActivity(new Intent(this, newone.class));

    } else if (position == 3) {
        start_Customdate();
    }

}`
```

Comment: I sugggest you read this http://andbook.anddev.org/. It's really a nice introduction to android. The missing piece in your app is Intents.

Comment: This question has mulitple duplicates. Please read [ask] to understand hpw [SO] works.  The search function is excellent and will save you time.  Please see [duplicates of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+to+navigate+to+another+screen)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 startActivity(new Intent(From.this,To.class));
```

Also in manifest file sign All the activities you used

Answer (score 1):

Android use Intent objects for sending messages between Activities and opening/starting new Activities.

I suggest you to read this:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html
and/or go through these 3 exercises:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent=new Intent(source.this,destination.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Please provide links to documentation in your answers and some explantion rather than just writing code.

Comment: @Merlin If you provide code.You got practice too.So it is better to provide code rather than link.

Comment: "rather than **just** writing code" ... I meant both code **and** explanation with references.

Answer (score 0):

You start a new intent inside your click listener

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(adapterAndListener);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
   int position, long id) {

      Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
      CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

   }
});
```

You can find more information about ListView in the following example:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Comment: I have two methods onCreate() and onListItemClick().Where to call new activity...in onCreate() or in onListItemClick() method?

Comment: in the onListItemClick method. if you put it in onCreate of your first activity it would immediately start the second activity. :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside ur listview onclick use this code,

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
```

Comment: he's using a listview not a button

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rasel's response. 
On top of this you can consider using `startActivityForResult()` / `onActivityResult()` should your daughter `Activity` need to send back something to its parent.

More details here:

- [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)
- [onActivityResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)