# how to add onlclick listener android

Tags: android, xml, class

Ok so I have multiple buttons on the home page of my android application.

I have seem to have got confused along the way as I have coded the app like this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void aboutus (final View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.aboutus);
    System.out.println("about us clicked"); 
}
```

And I have put the on click in the xml.

However I have things that I need to write code for in the "about us" page.

In my about us class I have the following

```
public class AboutUs extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aboutus);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void onBackPressed() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Here is the xml code for the button that is being clicked

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:layout_width="134dp"
    android:layout_height="97dp"
    android:layout_x="16dp"
    android:layout_y="150dp"
    android:onClick="aboutus"
    android:src="@drawable/aboutus" />
```

Any code I am writing isn't working on that page? I don't know why? can any one help?

Thank you.

Comment: i m not unclear with ur question, u r adding onClick in xml? so when u click that button what happens?

Comment: Sorry, when i click the button the correct xml page loads. But none of the code in the class of the button click isn't working? @Monica Ive posted my xml

Comment: Well, this isn't how you change views in android, if you want to navigate into another view, you need to start another `Activity`, here's how you'll do it. [How to navigate from one screen to another screen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1102050/593709) and a blog entry [Android Activity – From One Screen To Another Screen](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen/)

Comment: You need to change the structure of your code.

Comment: NARESH REDDY is right check his ans and also add your other class in manifest

Comment: public void aboutus (final View view) change to View view and use switch and check which view is been clicked

Comment: What you want to do `onClick` of `ImageButton`?

Comment: @PratikButani i want to load another view which has its own code within its own class :\

Comment: Do you mean another `Activity`?

Comment: @PratikButani yeah sorry.

Comment: I have improved My Answer Check this below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change your `MainActivity` like this:**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void aboutus(final View view)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUs.class));
    }
```

**and `AboutUs.java` is like:**

```
public class AboutUs extends Activity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aboutus);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /* No need of this method */
    public void onBackPressed() {
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

#### **NOTE:**

`android:onClick` is for **API level 4** onwards, so if you're **targeting < 1.6**, then you can't use it.

Comment: Its giving me a error saying that i haven't declared the activity in the android manifest xml?

Comment: then you have to define `Activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `setContentView()` to call another `Activity`.
You must use Intents

```
Intent in = new Intent(this,AboutUs.class);
startActivity(in);
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more so i understand please?

Comment: When you are using setContentView you will be in the same activity so clicks you handled in second actvity won't work here so when you want to change to another activity use Intents

Answer (score 0):

You can't just call `setContentView` in your aboutus method, you need to create an intent that starts a new activity.  Calling `setContentView` just sets the view in the current main activity, and doesn't instantiate your `AboutUs` activity class.  Your `aboutus` method should look similar to:

```
public void aboutus (final View view)
{   
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutUs.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```