# What function should i use to open the activities of each button on android studio?

Tags: android

I'm having small problem on my project. I can't open the activities of each button after clicking it. I don't know if the codes I used are correct. please help me fix it. Thank you.

**activity_main2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity2"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundimg">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:text="Sleep"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.299" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:text="Stress Reliever"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.433" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:text="Calm"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.57" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:text="Motivational Quotes"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.701" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/goodday"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Good Day,"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20pt"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.078"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Melana!"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="17pt"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.059"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.112" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity2.java**

```
package com.example.serenityapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

Button butt1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    butt1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    butt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_stress);
        }
    });


}

}
```

[This is what the app looks like and the four buttons should open their respective activities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xmGi.png)

Comment: ` public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_stress);
        }` don't know why you think this _would_ work, finding how to navigate to different activities is just a simple search away

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102050/how-to-navigate-from-one-screen-to-another-screen

Comment: Don't use `setContentView()` on button click. Instead, create new activities and open them using intent.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example. As someone answered here, you could just search how to start a new activity.

```
butt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent navigateToAnotherActivity = new Intent(this, SleepActivity.class);
            startActivity(navigateToAnotherActivity);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

to navigate from one activity to another `intent` is used

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class)
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in the screenshot you provided. You have created 4 different activities. You just need to open them using the below code.

This code goes inside the `onCreate()` method of `MainActivity2`

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button bt_Sleep, bt_Stress_Reliever, bt_Calm, bt_Motivational_Quotes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        bt_Sleep = findViewById(R.id.button);
        bt_Stress_Reliever = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bt_Calm = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        bt_Motivational_Quotes = findViewById(R.id.button3);

        bt_Sleep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent sleep = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, sleep.class);
                startActivity(sleep);
            }
        });

        bt_Stress_Reliever.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent stressReliever = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, stress.class);
                startActivity(stressReliever);
            }
        });

        bt_Calm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //calm change with your actual activity name
                Intent calmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, calm.class);
                startActivity(calmIntent);
            }
        });

        bt_Motivational_Quotes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //motivational_quotes change with your actual activity name
                Intent mq = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, motivational_quotes.class);
                startActivity(mq);
            }
        });

    }   
}
```

This code should work.
Still facing problem comment here.