# How can i get my buttons working for Android Studio?

Tags: android

I have an Activity which has two buttons on it. The first button adds the user data to a database and the second takes us to a different activity. The buttons in my main activity are working but not in this activity.  The code seems to be correct.

Activity:

```
public class addData extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText addName, addAge, addWeight;
    Button addDatatoDB, goToCalcIntake;
    personInfo personInfodDB;
    final int ltrPerKg = 30;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_data);

        addName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addName);
        addWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addWeight);
        addAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addAge);

        addDatatoDB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addDatatoDatabase);
        goToCalcIntake = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goTo);
        personInfodDB = new personInfo(getApplicationContext());



       addDatatoDB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               String name = addName.getText().toString().trim();
               int weight = Integer.valueOf(addWeight.getText().toString().trim());
               int age = Integer.valueOf(addAge.getText().toString().trim());
               int intake = weight/ltrPerKg;
               personInfodDB.addInfo(name,weight,age,intake);
           }
       });

        goToCalcIntake.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                setContentView(R.layout.show_intake);
            }
        });;
    }

}
```

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/goTo"
    android:layout_width="168dp"
    android:layout_height="77dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:text="Calculate your intake here" />
```

Comment: Second onclick is wrong.Use intent to redirect on second activity UI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to navigate from one screen to another screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102050/how-to-navigate-from-one-screen-to-another-screen)

Comment: Are you sure that your activity has that button? If so, can sure that your button are clickable?

Comment: Could you try adding a log statement inside each `onClick` method (e.g. `Log.i("whatever prefix you want", "Add data clicked");`) and check logcat to see if these handlers are actually being called?

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
goToCalcIntake.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
               Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, show_intake.class);
                    startActivity(i);
            }
        });;
```

I assume that your next activity is called "show_intake"
I cut the code my own working project.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. It's not showing any errors. It doesn't respond whatsoever. The other button is also not responding.

Comment: can you share the whole code?

Answer (score -1):

make sure you declare and initialize.

declare

```
Button goToCalcIntake;
```

initialize

```
goToCalcIntake= findViewById(R.id.btnaddStudent);
```